# complex razor function or helper

Tags: function, razor, helper

I have a data model with a dozen properties, say value1, value2, value3 (actually they have meaningful names but that's not important here).

In my display, I need to do the following for each value:

```
@if (Model.Value1 >= 2)
{ 
    <div class="col-sm-6 test-box-item">
        <h5>@Html.DisplayNameFor(_ => Model.Value1)</h5>
        <div>@Model.Value1</div>
    </div>
}
```

This for a dozen of them.

I wanted to create a @function or @helper and simplify the code to something like:

```
DisplayValue(_ => Model.Value1)
DisplayValue(_ => Model.Value2)
...
```

but couldn't figure out how to do that.

Any idea? I guess I need a function that accepts an Expression but I really don't know how to code that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this helper

```
public static class HmtlExtensions
{
    public static HtmlString DisplayValue<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) 
            throw (new ArgumentNullException("expression"));

        var result = new StringBuilder();

        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

        // get value
        var _value = metadata.Model.ToString();

        int value = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(_value, out value) && value >= 2)
        {
            result.Append("<div class=\"col-sm-6 test-box-item\"><h5>");
            result.Append(helper.DisplayNameFor(expression));
            result.Append("</h5><div>");
            result.Append(_value);
            result.Append("</div></div>");
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

and in your view use it like

```
@Html.DisplayValue(x => x.Value1)
@Html.DisplayValue(x => x.Value2)
@Html.DisplayValue(x => x.Value3)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.